# How do you set up the __contains__ method in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, contains

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly set up a **contains** method in my class. I know it automatically uses the operator "in" when you call it, i just don't think I understand how to set it up correctly.

I have to use it to see if anotherCircle is contained within a specific circle (both input from the user). The prof had us do two different types of methods for this.

The first one I have no problems with and more or less understand what it is doing, It is as follows:

```
def contains(self, circle2d):
  dist = math.sqrt((circle2d._x - self._x)**2 + (circle2d._y - self._y)**2) #Distance of second circle's coords from the first circle's coords
  if dist + circle2d._radius <= self._radius:
     return True
```

However, the next method, which is supposed to do the same thing, uses the **contains** method so that we can call it with **in** in the main function. All I have is this:

```
def __contains__(self, anotherCircle):
    if anotherCircle in self:
        return True
```

I get multiple errors when I try to run this. I think i'm missing something on self, but I'm not sure what? Could someone please try to explain to me what exactly you need to do when you're writing a **contains** method such as this?

Comment: `if anotherCircle self` isn't that calling __contains__ in itself? Shouldn't you be doing `return self.contains(anotherCircle)` in the method body?

Comment: I don't know. I guess that's what I was asking

Comment: yeah you're calling `__contains__` recursively when you're using "in" inside `__contains__`.

Comment: Yes what you said actually worked! Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `__contains__` method on an object doesn't *call* `in`; rather, it is what the `in` operator calls.

When you write

```
if circle1 in circle2:
```

The python interpreter will see that `circle2` is a Circle object, and will look for a `__contains__` method defined for it. It will essentially try to call

```
circle2.__contains__(circle1)
```

This means that you need to write your `__contains__` method without using `in`, or else you will be writing a recursive method that never ends.

Comment: Okay, so if in calls the contain method, then how do you write the method to be called by in?

Comment: You write it just like your original `contains` method -- the code in there looks exactly like what you need -- except that you might want to return False if self doesn't contain circle2d

Answer (score 2):

Your `__contains__` method **must** use the same logic as your original `contains` method. Otherwise how will Python know what it means for one circle to contain another? You have to tell it, that's what the `__contains__` method is for. You can either get `__contains__` to call `contains`, or just put the whole code in that method instead.